# Linux netlink kernel socket arp cache getter (similar to ip ne)

Tags: c, linux, networking

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>


#define ENTRY(x) {x, #x}
#define STRING_M(x) #x

static int parse_rtattr(struct rtattr *tb[], int max, struct rtattr *rta, int len) {
    /* loop over all rtattributes */
    while (RTA_OK(rta, len) && max--) {
        tb[rta->rta_type] = rta; /* store attribute ptr to the tb array */
        rta = RTA_NEXT(rta, len); /* special rtnetlink.h macro to get next netlink route attribute ptr */
    };
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status;
    void *p; //just a ptr

    /* open socket */
    int sd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_ROUTE);

    /* contruct arp cache request */
    struct {
        struct nlmsghdr n;
        struct ndmsg ndm;
        char buf[1024];
    } req = {
            .n.nlmsg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct ndmsg)),
            .n.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ROOT, /* to get all table instead of a single entry */
            .n.nlmsg_type = RTM_GETNEIGH, /* to get arp cache */
            .ndm.ndm_family = AF_INET, /* IP protocol family. AF_INET/AF_INET6 */
    };

    /* send request */
    status = send(sd, &req, req.n.nlmsg_len, 0);

    /* this is buffer to store an answer */
    char buf[16384] = {0};

    /* get an answer */
    status = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    int buf_size = status; /* recv will return answer size */
    p = (void *) buf; /* set p to start of an answer */

    while (buf_size > 0) { /* loop while buffer size is more than 0 */
        struct nlmsghdr *answer = (struct nlmsghdr *) p; /* netlink header structure */

        int len = answer->nlmsg_len; /* netlink message length including header */
        struct ndmsg *msg = NLMSG_DATA(answer); /* macro to get a ptr right after header */
        /* Given the payload length, len, this macro returns the aligned
         * length to store in the nlmsg_len field of the nlmsghdr.
         * */
        int msg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*msg));
        len -= msg_len; /* count message length left */
        p += msg_len; /* move ptr forward */

        /* rtnetlink route netlink attributes buffer */
        struct rtattr *tb[NDA_MAX + 1] = {0};

        /* this is very first rtnetlink attribute */
        struct rtattr *rta = (struct rtattr *) p;
        memset(tb, 0, sizeof(tb)); /* clear attribute buffer */
        parse_rtattr(tb, NDA_MAX, rta, len); /* fill tb attribute buffer */
        if (tb[NDA_DST]) { /* this is destination address */
            char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
            inet_ntop(msg->ndm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[NDA_DST]), ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s ", ip);
        }
        if (tb[NDA_LLADDR]) { /* this is hardware mac address */
            const unsigned char *addr = RTA_DATA(tb[NDA_LLADDR]);
            fprintf(stderr, "lladdr: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",
                    addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3], addr[4], addr[5]);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "lladdr: \n");
        }

        p += len;
        buf_size -= answer->nlmsg_len;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For two days, I was looking for a sample code on how to get the raw ARP cache from the Linux kernel.  The code should be without dependencies and as simple as possible. I haven't yet found anything useful so I've made my own ARP utility analog.

Maybe there is something to do better?

Answer (score 3):

Small review.

> Code should be ... simple as possible.

**Unneeded casts**

```
// p = (void *) buf;
p = buf;
...
// struct rtattr *rta = (struct rtattr *) p;
struct rtattr *rta = p;
```

**Unused**

Remove unused code.

```
// #define ENTRY(x) {x, #x}
// #define STRING_M(x) #x
```

**Unneeded large initialization**

`char buf[16384] = {0};` zeros a large buffer, yet is not needed for `recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);`

```
// char buf[16384] = {0};
char buf[16384];
```

Zero-ing of `tb` not needed

```
// memset(tb, 0, sizeof(tb));
```

**Unneeded `()`**

```
// recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);`
recv(sd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);`
```

**Unused status**

`status` from `status = send(sd, &req, req.n.nlmsg_len, 0);` is not used.  Either omit or better: check status.

**Unneeded zeroing - twice**

Below, `tb` is zeo'd twice and then written again.  Zero-ings not needed.

```
    // struct rtattr *tb[NDA_MAX + 1] = {0};
    struct rtattr *tb[NDA_MAX + 1];

    // struct rtattr *rta = (struct rtattr *) p;
    struct rtattr *rta = p;

    // memset(tb, 0, sizeof(tb));

    parse_rtattr(tb, NDA_MAX, rta, len); /* fill tb attribute buffer */
```

---

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

1024 in `char buf[1024];` undocumented.  Why 1024?

**On the edge**

`inet_ntop(msg->ndm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[NDA_DST]), ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);` lacks return value check for errors.

**Minor: Sign-ness change**

Rather than use `int`, use the same sign-ness and type as `answer->nlmsg_len`.

```
int len = answer->nlmsg_len;
__u32 len = answer->nlmsg_len;
// or
unsigned long len = answer->nlmsg_len;
```

`struct rtattr *RTA_NEXT(struct rtattr *rta, unsigned int rtabuflen);` expects an unsigned, not an `int`.

```
// static int parse_rtattr(struct rtattr *tb[], int max, struct rtattr *rta, int len) {
static int parse_rtattr(struct rtattr *tb[], int max, struct rtattr *rta, unsigned len) {
```